# Why are most BLDC motors designed to operate on low voltages?

Tags: power-supply, brushless-dc-motor

The vast majority of brushless DC motors I encounter operate on low voltages such as 1.5V to 24V. Obviously, if the intended application is for runnning strictly on battery power, it makes sense. I do, however, occasionally see them in some modern household appliances and they use relatively complex power supplies to operate at the same low voltage range.

What is the reason for not designing them to operate at 90V to 220V range. Is the circuitry for commutating the motor at higher voltages more expensive or less efficient?

Comment: Because BLDCs are *DC*. High voltage DC source are not that common.

Comment: What about treadmills?  Most have DC brushed motors.

Comment: I must say that compared to SO, this site has a much friendlier user community.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'd argue BLDCs is a misnomer.... They are not really DC motors... The plug-them-in-and-go variety may require a DC voltage, but that's not what is happening at the actual motor part.

Comment: @Trevor If you get right down to it, even a brushed DC motor isn't truly DC, because the current in the rotor switches direction. The (very simplified!) difference comes down to simply that in a BLDC motor the commutation is electronic, and in a brushed motor it's mechanical.

Comment: @Felthry yes indeed.

Comment: Anything in electronics is not DC from this perspective. It has clocks, ramps, transitions. Let's not go into that :)

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, brushless DC motors are not strictly speaking DC motors. They are really synchronous AC motors in disguise driven by a variable frequency driver (VFD) with some tight feedback.

Though they can be, and sometimes are, driven with large voltages, that adds some awkward side effects like, increased switching requirements, more electrical noise, and dangerous DC voltages.

Since you end up needing to down-volt to drive your control system anyway, it makes more sense to use motors down in that range also. As such there is higher demand for lower voltage motors than high voltage variants.

Comment: Trevor...that sounds like a very broad guess rather than a definitive 'writing this because I know' answer to a question about voltage levels. Sorry but... :-)

Comment: @TonyM, I agree. I'm not happy with the last line either, but not sure how else to rephrase.... perhaps, "the demand dictates the market.."

Comment: LOL!  Yeah, when I read the last line I thought well 24V is still too high for a 555, but then thought about the BLDCs in disc players which operate around 5V.

Answer (score 0):

BLDC motors are typically permanent magnet synchronous motors, which work with an external controller (hobby folks call this an 'ESC').

For use in appliances up to industrial applications where the supply is directly from the mains it's more common to use "3-phase induction motors" (which are actually **also BLDC, but not usually called that**). Again an external controller is used (industrial folks call this a 'VFD'). Typically the motors would run from about RMS mains voltage (maximum) at a variable frequency. So inside the controller there is a DC bus that is roughly the peak mains voltage or double the peak mains voltage in the case of doublers. So it could be 300VDC. The motor sees (say) 50-240VRMS at (say) 10 to 200Hz, with peak voltages approaching +/-300VDC.

Whether it's called BLDC or AC induction the motors are AC motors. It's the controller that takes a DC bus (or an AC single or 3-phase input converted to DC) and inverts that to create the AC waveforms your motor craves.

Comment: 3phase induction machines "usually called BLDC" oO

Comment: A while back, I asked if it is possible to use an ESC as a VFD by simply stepping up the output phase voltages. I was told that it would be too costly. When you consider the cost between an ESC and a VFD from eBay, the cost shouldn't still be quite cheaper.  Alternatively, you could use IGBTs to amplify the phases.